# Insert rows when certain Cell is reached

Tags: vba, excel

kind of new/self-taught.
I have a sheet that contains 20 lines which people are putting info into.
sometimes they need more than the 20 lines.
So what I am looking for is a VBA that will copy a range and then insert it below these 20 lines of filled out info.
So when C20 is filled out-> copy range -> insert A34.

Problem is I have no idea how to start on this, and I cant find similar coding on the forum, that I can tweak to my purpose.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are very new to VBA it helps to record macros with the recorder and look at the code. Then think about what to change (or check) to make sure it works when another 20 lines are added...

Comment: To automatically run your code you use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` in the sheet-module. You will find examples with these hints and you can try and come back if you encounter problems.

Comment: Thank you for the auto run hint :) did not know about that one. I do use the record macro function to learn and figure out what does what. But the code for checking that cell is what I'm unsure about. I imagine its some kind of "if" statement? if range as greater then zero, then copy paste, if not, do nothing.

Comment: Yes, first check if target is the cell / range you want to act on. Then check if its value is `<> ""` and if it is, do your copy paste. (remember to think about what happens after that (is your range still filled with values? If they are filled again, where to copy then? What if not all cells are filled? What if your range below had values? and so on...)

Comment: Edit your question with encountered problems and the code you have after trying and someone wil help you further.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. got it working. but now the Code loops checking the cell and then pasting the other content, over and over until excel crashes. is there a way to stop previous code when it detects that a value have been pasted? So when C20 is filled out-> copy range -> insert A34. and then if A34 have value stop previous if function.

Comment: sure :)  At the beginning of your `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` add `Application.EnableEvents=false` and at the end of the sub `Application.EnableEvents=true`. That stops other (or the same) event-procedure to fire when you copy/paste your values.

Comment: Holy C***! its works like a charm! Thank you so much for your help! ill edit my post and put in the result when done, so hopeful other people will find this useful as well.

Comment: You are welcome! I wrote some code, so you can compare your result with mine.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. but somehow I screwed it up. 
my code starts as:

`Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("B20").Value <> "" Then
    Rows("1:28").Select`

but it doesn't really do anything when b20 is filled with info, its like it doesn't check the range.

Comment: Its better to check target and not to use select. Please try my code below, put it in the sheet-module, set a breakpoint (or insert `stop` after the line `Set CopyRange...`) and use F8 to go stepwise through the code and check the variable-values. It will help you understand the logik behind it.

Comment: OK I tried using yours. didn't work.
But when I made new workbook and used yours on an empty sheet, it worked.
so its something in the existing workbook that stops the macro from going it seems.

Comment: Possibly you got an eeor on your code and it didnt get to `EnableEvents=True`...

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, if you found a working solution with the hints provided. You can check your code against my example (with comments) and maybe learn something from the differences:

```
Option Explicit     ' should be always on top of your module (enforces variable declaration)


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CopyRange As Range, DestRange As Range
Set CopyRange = Me.Range("C1:C20")
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub     ' exit if more than 1 cell is changed at a time
    If Application.Intersect(Target, CopyRange.Cells(CopyRange.Cells.Count)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      'exits if its not the last cell of your copyrange that has been changed

    Set DestRange = Me.Range("C34")
    Do Until IsEmpty(DestRange.Value)       ' moves the destination down if alreade been used (if you add 40, 60, 80 infos)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Offset(20, 0)
    Loop

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    CopyRange.Copy DestRange
    CopyRange.ClearContents     'clears the copyrange so that more data can be entered
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```